# Unable to select a database from EC2 instance to RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, database-connection, database-schema, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to a MYSQL-RDS database using an EC2 instance. I am able to connect to the database, but not able to select any schema. The EC2 instance is on a VPC. Using Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried connecting to the database and selecting it from my local machine which is also has access to the VPC.

I checked the privileges on the MYSQL server and have verified that the username/password/ip that match what the EC2 instance is using.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using CentOS make shure SELlinux is configured correctly too. Had this problem today. Also make shure the security group(s) are configured.

Comment: I should've specified my Linux version and distribution. Edited question. Using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: *"not able to select any schema"* does not have a sufficiently precise meaning to be helpful.  Please explain *exactly* what you are trying to do, and *exactly* what error message is being returned.